# Require minimum NDK version in Android project?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I have an Android project that has to have a specific version of the NDK, at minimum. So far I haven't been able to find a way to require NDK versions in any way. The best I can think of is to possibly have a pre-build step that checks the version and fails the build if the version doesn't match.

Is there any official, or at better, way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean minimum android version?

Comment: No, I already have the min and target Android Version set up. This is specifically the NDK, due to some bug fixes above a specific version that directly affected the native code in my app.